# real numbers become complex in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, complex-numbers

the code is :

```
A = b/a
B = c/a
C = d/a

Q = (A**2-3*B)/9
R = (2*A**3-9*A*B+27*C)/54

M = R**2-Q**3

p = (3*B-A**2)/3
q = (2*A**3-9*A*B+27*C)/27

delta = (q/2)**2+(p/3)**3

if M <= 0 :
    from math import sqrt,acos,cos,pi

    Z = acos(R/sqrt(Q**3))
    X1 = -(2*sqrt(Q)*cos(Z/3))-A/3
    X2 = -(2*sqrt(Q)*cos((Z+2*pi)/3))-A/3
    X3 = -(2*sqrt(Q)*cos((Z-2*pi)/3))-A/3


elif delta > 0 :
    from math import sqrt
    import cmath

    u = ((-q/2)+sqrt(delta))**(1/3)
    v = ((q/2)+sqrt(delta))**(1/3)

    X1 = u-v-A/3
    X2 = -(1/2)*(u-v)-A/3+(u+v)*(sqrt(3)/2)*cmath.sqrt(-1)
    X3 = -(1/2)*(u-v)-A/3-(u+v)*(sqrt(3)/2)*cmath.sqrt(-1)
```

it gives me wrong answers when i enter :

```
a = 1 b = 1 c = -1 d = -1
M == 0
```

but it skips M and goes to delta

and the results are :

```
X1 = 1.0
X2 = (-1+4.8e-09j)
X3 = (-1-4.8e-09j)
```

i don't know what is wrong ?
it is suppose to go to M and X1 , X2 and X3 become real by calculating in M

Comment: Your example code has an `elif` with no preceding `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative number raised to a fractional power either gives a complex number (in Python 3.x) (Even for an odd power like 1/3 or 1/5) or a Value error in Python 2.x (`ValueError: negative number cannot be raised to a fractional power`).

Example -

```
>>> (-27)**(1/3)
(1.5000000000000004+2.598076211353316j)
```

You would need to handle that case yourself, example, if you are doing power of (1/3) , you will have to handle it like -

```
x = -27
if x < 0:
    pow = -((-x) **(1/3))
elif x > 0:
    pow = x **(1/3)
else:
    pow = 0
```

Comment: another problem above

Comment: Q = (A**2-3*B)/9
        R = (2*A**3-9*A*B+27*C)/54
        M = R**2-Q**3
if M <= 0 :
        from math import sqrt,acos,cos,pi
        
        Z = acos(R/sqrt(Q**3))
        X1 = -(2*sqrt(Q)*cos(Z/3))-A/3
        X2 = -(2*sqrt(Q)*cos((Z+2*pi)/3))-A/3
        X3 = -(2*sqrt(Q)*cos((Z-2*pi)/3))-A/3                                                             when i enter 1 1 -1 -1 M == 0 but it goes to delta and solve                    X2 = (-1+4.8e-09j)
X3 = (-1-4.8e-09j)

Comment: Again, your `u` and `v` are calculated in the same way , using  `((q/2)+sqrt(delta))**(1/3)` , this can cause complex numbers, as i indicated in my answer, you can write a function that does the second code in my answer, and call that function for doing cube root.

Comment: when i enter a = 1 b = 1 c = -1 d = -1 M = 0 my code is if M <= 0  then  it calculate three real numbers but when M = 0 it skips M and goes to delta and X2 and X3 become complex

Comment: Where are you using `M` I cannot see any `M` in the code in your question

Comment: i will edit the question above to show you what i mean

Comment: When you pass in those values M is not <= 0. M is `1.3877787807814457e-17` , maybe you can use `M = round(M,10)` . It may work.

Comment: Q = 4/9       R = -8/27

Comment: sorry? I didn't understand that?

Comment: When a = 1 b = 1 c = -1 d = -1 Q = 4/9 and R = -8/27   then M equals zero

Comment: not in python, python's floats do not work that way, use what i said , round it to some number of decimal places like 5 or 10